# How to summarize a formula field in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

How do I add a running total or summary field on a formula field in crystal reports?

```
// Sample Report

 Serial No.       Premium        Commission         Net (Premium-Commission)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1.              10               4                    6        
    2.              40              30                   10
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Grand Total       50              34                   16
```

In sample report, Net (Premium-Commission) is a formula field which gets evaluated for each row? How do I add a grand total/summary field for my formula?  It seems we can add a summary field to only `Command fields.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose `Net (Premium-Commission)` formula field name is `{@Net}`. Now you have to create another three formula fields.

1. **Initializer:** this formula filed will be placed in header section to reset all variables.
2. **Increment:** this formula field will be placed in detail section to summarize the value.
3. **Total:** this formula field will be placed in footer section to show total of `{@Net}`.

Code will be writen in formula fields as below.

`{@Initializer}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar dSum :=0;`

`{@Increment}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar dSum;   //Don't initialize zero
dSum:=dSum+{@Net}; //{@Net} formula field must be return numeric value`

`{@Total}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar dSum;   //Don't initialize zero
dSum;`

Place all formula fields in their appropriate section and suppress `{@Initializer}` and `{@Increment}` formula field.

Comment: You are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any calculation then that is not possible but one workaround would be to sum the each row and reset it in `header`.

1. Create a formula `@Intialize` in that write below code:

`Shared NumberVar count;
count:=0`

1. In detail write below formula and place it after `Net (Premium-Commission)`.

Shared NumberVar count;

Count:=count+<>

\
3. Now create one more formula @Display and place it in footer.

`Shared NumberVar count;
count;`