# How sum a formula field in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

[image: crystal report]
i have a formula field caled (late) which the result of subtract 9 AM - Checkin filed  , how to sum late  for each group

## Crystal_Report

Comment: I have the same pobrlem. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779273/how-to-summarize-a-formula-field-in-crystal-reports

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Running Total Field that available at the Field Explorer.
Choose "Sum" as the type of summary

Comment: it show that "sum" in Running Total available only to table filed not for formula field